# Break and Continue Alternative

Tags: javascript, html

I want to know if there's any alternative other then using break and continue statement. Here's my code

```js
var i = 100;
var out = " ";
while (true) {
  i -= 2

  if (i % 6 == 0) {
    out += i + " ";
    continue;
  }
  if (i % 4 == 0) {
    out += i + " ";
    continue;
  }
  if (i % 7 == 0 && i % 5 == 0) {
    break;
  }
}
console.log(out);
```

Comment: Why are you looking for an alternative?

Comment: because the question ask to retype the coding that has been produce without using break and continue. My lecturer won't teach me and I'm stuck with this

Comment: @Marty `break` and `continue` in loops are a code smell.

Comment: @JLRishe That is one of many reasons but I was asking specifically what the OP's reason was.

Comment: @JLRishe - "break and continue in loops are a code smell."  So are do-while loops.

Comment: @Clinton If you want to get into that, I think all loops are a code smell. Why is `for` any better than `do-while`? Especially a WET `for`?

Comment: @JLRishe - Because, a do-while loop is GUARANTEED to go through the loop once, whether it is needed or not.  In a while or for loop, if you pass in a value that is both divisible by 7 and 5, no code is run.  If you pass in a value that is both divisible by 7 and 5 in a do-while loop, then the subtraction line and the if statement are both run for no reason at all.  Of the three looping structures, for should be used most often, while sometimes, and do-while almost never, because in all but rare cases, it is guaranteed to run code without needing to.

Comment: @JLRishe - Again, I'm not trying to be a jerk.  I just want the original poster to have all the information possible.

Comment: @Clinton Your `for` loop doesn't avoid the initial subtraction. You just sidestepped it by manually changing the initial value of `i` ahead of time. So the only (potentially) extraneous execution in the `do-while` is the evaluation of the `if` condition. I'm willing to take that performance hit.

Comment: @JLRishe - I only "sidestepped" the initial value because the while loop in the original post is contrived and you would NEVER do something like that in a real project.  The notion of passing in a value that you know you don't want from the outset is ludicrous.  You're welcome, of course, to do whatever you want, but using a do-while loop is a good way to be rejected in a code review.  In the real world, a do-while loop is almost always the wrong looping mechanism to use.

Comment: @JLRsihe - Look at your own do-while loop, for example.  It produces inconsistent and inaccurate results.  You're passing in a value of 100 to the loop, but it isn't being included in the results because you're screwing around with the initial value.  Passing in 102 does include 100, which is unexpected, since it wasn't included when you passed in 100.  This makes your do-while loop buggy.  The ONLY correct and consistent answer on this page so far is my for loop.  Check for yourself.  Run all code blocks with various values and see what you get.

Comment: @Clinton _"The ONLY correct and consistent answer on this page so far is my for loop. Check for yourself. Run all code blocks with various values and see what you get."_ I have no idea what you're talking about here, but if this is true, it should easy for you to provide a value of `i` where my code produces a different result from the original code. I can provide you several (including the _provided example value_ where your `for` loop produces a different result from the original code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159938/discussion-between-clinton-and-jlrishe).

Answer (score 2):

You can use `if-else` and `do-while`:

```js
var i = 100;
var out = " ";
do {
  i -= 2

  if (i % 6 == 0) {
    out += i + " ";
  } else if (i % 4 == 0) {
    out += i + " ";
  }
} while (!(i % 7 == 0 && i % 5 == 0));

console.log(out);
```

Since the body of the `if` and `else` are the same, you can combine them using `||`:

```js
var i = 100;
var out = " ";
do {
  i -= 2

  if (i % 6 == 0 || i % 4 == 0) {
    out += i + " ";
  }
} while (!(i % 7 == 0 && i % 5 == 0));

console.log(out);
```

Comment: The original poster can accomplish the code in a while loop without using break and continue.  There's no need to switch it to a do-while loop.  If they were going to switch, I'd recommend a for loop over the do-while loop, since it does a better job of encapsulating the i variable and also doesn't run through the loop once if there isn't a need.

Comment: @Clinton Yeah, they don't _have to_ use a `do-while` loop, but I don't see any reason not to change it into a `do-while`. I think the way you've shoehorned it into a `while` loop by subtracting 2 from `i` in three different places is ghastly. Your `for` example suffers from the same problem because you're doing the subtraction in two different places.

Comment: @JLRishe - I agree with the while loop version.  I only gave it as an example in case the professor required a while loop solution.  You are mistaken on the for loop.  It only subtracts 2 from i once.

do-while loops are a different construct than while and for loops.  They go through the code one time no matter what.  There's no reason to subtract 2 from i and run through the if statement if the conditions are going to be true to start with, so the for loop is going to be the most elegant and efficient way to solve this looping task.

Comment: @Clinton You are pre-subtracting 2 from the initial value of `i`. That's what I meant when I said it involves subtracting in two places.

Comment: @JLRishe - Exactly! Why would you create a loop that accepts values you don't use? In the OP's code, and yours, you allow people to pass in 100, which should be in the output, but since you're altering the initial value. If you don't want 100 to be included in the results, you should write another if conduction to exclude it, not create a do-while loop that ONLY excludes it in cases where it is passed in, but not in cases when you pass in 104, for instance. Your code produces inconsistent results and wouldn't pass code review.

Comment: @JLRishe - Your code is a good example of why do-while loops and fiddling with initial values are bad. They run code unnecessarily and have unintended side effects. For example, if I pass 100 into your loop, my output should be "100 96 92 90 88 84 80 78 76 72," but it isn't. 100 is excluded. However, if I pass 102, 100 IS included in the list, but 102 isn't, even though it should be. Your code produces unreliable results. My for loop produces the correct results in all cases.  If you pass in 100, it will be included in the list. If you pass in 102, the list is still correct. Make sense?

Comment: @Clinton I don't know where you got on this trip about how 100 should be included in the output if it's the starting value, to the point where you keep repeating it over and over. Not including the input value is a _characteristic of the original code's behavior_. You can't just tell the person supplying an input to your algorithm "No, your input is wrong. Subtract 2 from it before you give it to me so I can avoid an extra step." This `do-while` loop produces the same results as the original code _for the same input value_, which your `for` loop doesn't do.

Comment: @JLRishe - Because, writing any function or loop that accepts a value and then doesn't operate on that value, but changes it to something else before using it, is a bad design. The OP's example is a contrived example from school, so it is forgivable, but to suggest that he fix that bad design by not only embracing it, but making it worse with a do-while loop is simply bad advice. I myself am wondering why you keep defending your do-while loop when it is obviously the wrong solution on many levels?

Comment: @Clinton Now you're claiming that a `do-while` is worse than a `while(true)` with two `break`s, a `continue`, and two extraneous `if`s? Look, man, I don't know where you formed your opinions about code quality, but I don't want anything to do with them.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159939/discussion-between-clinton-and-jlrishe).

Answer (score 1):

The below should produce the same output:

```
var i = 100;
var out = " ";
var looping = true;
do {
  i -= 2;
  if (i % 6 == 0 || i % 4 == 0) {
    out += i + " ";
  } else if(i % 7 == 0 && i % 5 == 0) {
      looping = false;
  }
} while (looping);
console.log(out);
```

Comment: It produces the same output for that specific initial value of `i`, but not if it were, for example, `700`. The behavior is not equivalent.

Comment: You have to subtract 2 from i in the parameter list in the while loop, otherwise there are cases where this won't output the right values.  The reason is because in your test statement, you're testing against 100 the first time around, but in the original code, you'd be testing against 98, since the first line of the original while loop subtracted 2 from the variable i.

Comment: @evilReiko Indeed it does.

Comment: @evilReiko - As I mentioned to JLRishe, a do-while loop is not the same as a while loop because a do-while loop is guaranteed to go through the code at least once, whereas a while loop will skip the code entirely under the right conditions, which is nearly always preferable.

I'm not trying to argue with you both.  I'm simply pointing out, for the benefit of the original poster, that do-while loops should be avoided.  I think it is important to know what they are, but it is equally important to know that you'll almost never use them (or shouldn't, anyway).

Comment: @Clinton that's completely wrong. There are situations (like this OP) where you want execute some code at least once before testing the condition in the "while".

Comment: @evilReiko - No, it isn't "completely wrong." The OP's code is a poor design to start with.  Why would you write a loop that allows you to pass in values you don't want to use?  In this case, 100 satisfies the if statement, so it should be included in the list, but in this case, it isn't. That is a poor design to start with. As with nearly all loops, there is NOTHING in this code that requires the loop to run at least once.  If you pass in a value that meets the conditional from the beginning, why would you run through the loop for no reason? This is bad and would be rejected in a code review.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you HAVE to use a while loop, you could do it this way:

```
var i = 100;
var out = " ";
while (!((i - 2) % 7 == 0 && (i - 2) % 5 == 0)) {
  i -= 2

  if (i % 6 == 0 || i % 4 == 0) {
    out += i + " ";
  }
}
console.log(out);
```

Dealing with the minus 2 code three times seems ugly to me though.  Also, your code (and the previous example) are buggy in that passing 100 in produces "96 92 90 88 84 80 78 76 72," when it should include 100 as well.  Passing in 102 produces "100 96 92 90 88 84 80 78 76 72," but should include 102 as well.  The output is inconsistent and unexpected.  Therefore, I'd prefer a for loop, like this:

```
var out = " ";
for (i = 98; !(i % 7 == 0 && i % 5 == 0); i -= 2) {
  if (i % 6 == 0 || i % 4 == 0) {
    out += i + " ";
  }
}
console.log(out);
```

You have to start the for loop at 98 because that's really where your while loop is starting, since the first thing the while loop does is reduce i by 2.  By using this for loop, you're operating on the passed in value, instead of altering it be something else, which produces a consistent, expected result.

Comment: _"Also, your code (and the previous example) are buggy in that passing 100 in produces "96 92 90 88 84 80 78 76 72," when it should include 100 as well."_ On what basis are you asserting this? How do you know that 100 is supposed to be included? Is there some definition of the expected behavior that's visible to only you? The task was to provide code that produces the same result as the original code. You can't just claim that the original code is "wrong" because it doesn't make sense to you.

Comment: @JLRishe - Are you honestly trying to argue that this is a good design?  Your loop accepts a value then changes that value before operating on it. It runs through itself in cases where there is no reason to, and it outputs inconsistent, unreliable results. It isn't a matter of my understanding. It is a simple matter of poor code design and a lack of understanding how loops work. I'm trying to help you and the OP write better code. If you're not interested in doing so, and only interested in being "right," feel free to ignore my advice.

Comment: No, I've said nothing about whether it's a good or bad design. The task is about producing slightly better code that produces the same result as the original code. You can't change the requirements because you think the original code sucks. Focus on meeting the requirements first, then worry about quality. You've skipped step 1, claimed that step 1 is wrong, and gone straight to 2.

Comment: You've claimed several times that my `do-while` wouldn't pass a code review. Your `for` loop wouldn't pass a unit test because it produces the wrong output for the input it's given.

Comment: Are you saying you'd write a test that relied on a function/loop/method changing inputs before operating on them? Sounds like you need to refactor your code and tests.

Comment: But you have. You've even gone so far as to "correct" evilReiko's code to match your own. You've propagated a bad design, and to suggest that embracing a bad design is step 1 of the development process isn't helping the OP learn to write good code at any level. You should ALWAYS operate on the data passed to you; not change it first and then fiddle with it.

Comment: I've worked for Microsoft, Intel, Sun Microsystems, Novell, and Epson, and I can't think of a single development team in any of those organizations that would refactor code (which is what we're doing) without calling into question the validity/consistency of the code's inputs and outputs. Why bother refactoring at all if you're just going to propagate the same issues as "step 1" and make them worse by adding redundancy to them?

Comment: I didn't tell evilReiko what kind of code to use. I pointed out that her code didn't match the original code's output if the input was changed, which was true. She chose to change her code to a `do-while`, probably because it was the natural choice in this situation. _"Why bother refactoring at all if you're just going to propagate the same issues as "step 1" and make them worse by adding redundancy to them?"_ Ever heard of doing an exercise for the exercise's sake? That's all this was.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159940/discussion-between-clinton-and-jlrishe).